# How to pass array object parameter from vue website to google appscript to set google spreadsheet column value

Tags: vue.js, google-apps-script

First I create a website by vue and I pass parameter to my google appscript

vue function

```
    var appurl = "my google appscript url"
    this.$http.get(appurl, {
      params: {
        settingLink: this.settingLink,
        albumLink: this.albumLink,
        stepControl: this.stepControl,
        nav: this.navSetting,
      }
    }).then(response => {
      console.log(response);
    })
```

and I send parameter to google appscript

my google appscript

```
  function doGet(e) {
  var params = e.parameter;
  var settingLink = params.settingLink;
  var albumLink = params.albumLink;
  var stepControl = params.stepControl;
  var nav = params.nav;
  var SpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(settingLink);
  var SheetName = SpreadSheet.getSheetByName("gameSetting");
  SheetName.getRange("D2").setValue(stepControl);
  SheetName.getRange("E2").setValue(albumLink);
  SheetName.getRange("F2").setValue(nav[0].style);
  SheetName.getRange("G2").setValue(nav[1].style);
  SheetName.getRange("H2").setValue(nav[2].style);
  }
```

The parameter albumLink and stepControl are string so I success push it to my spreadsheet (figure 1)

but nav is an array object like (in vue data)

```
nav=[
     {style:"red",content:"test"},
     {style:"blue",content:"test"},
     {style:"green",content:"test"},
    ]
```

How could I let spreadsheet F2 as "red", G2 as "blue", and H2 as "green"

figure 1
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiVXv.png)

Comment: You could try to JSON.stringify it when you send it and then parse it on receive but it would be a lot easier to send through Google script run as an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By checking the output of `JSON.stringify(e)`, it seems that each property of objects become different parameters and are received as something like the following:

```
{
  "queryString": "settingLink=settingLinkTest&albumLink=albumLinkTest&stepControl=stepControlTest&nav%5B0%5D%5Bstyle%5D=red&nav%5B0%5D%5Bcontent%5D=test&nav%5B1%5D%5Bstyle%5D=blue&nav%5B1%5D%5Bcontent%5D=test&nav%5B2%5D%5Bstyle%5D=green&nav%5B2%5D%5Bcontent%5D=test",
  "contextPath": "",
  "parameters": {
    "nav[1][style]": [
      "blue"
    ],
    "nav[1][content]": [
      "test"
    ],
    "albumLink": [
      "albumLinkTest"
    ],
    "nav[2][style]": [
      "green"
    ],
    "settingLink": [
      "settingLinkTest"
    ],
    "nav[2][content]": [
      "test"
    ],
    "nav[0][style]": [
      "red"
    ],
    "stepControl": [
      "stepControlTest"
    ],
    "nav[0][content]": [
      "test"
    ]
  },
  "contentLength": -1,
  "parameter": {
    "nav[2][content]": "test",
    "nav[1][content]": "test",
    "albumLink": "albumLinkTest",
    "settingLink": "settingLinkTest",
    "nav[0][style]": "red",
    "stepControl": "stepControlTest",
    "nav[0][content]": "test",
    "nav[1][style]": "blue",
    "nav[2][style]": "green"
  }
}
```

Since the index of a particular *nav* and its properties become names of parameters, you can get their values by changing your doGet() to:

```
SheetName.getRange("F2").setValue(params["nav[0][style]"]);
SheetName.getRange("G2").setValue(params["nav[1][style]"]);
SheetName.getRange("H2").setValue(params["nav[2][style]"]);
```

Alternatively, as suggested in the comments of the question, you can stringify the *nav* object when sending it:

```
this.$http.get(appurl, {
          params: {
            settingLink: settingLink,
            albumLink: albumLink,
            stepControl: stepControl,
            nav: JSON.stringify(nav)
          }
        }).then(response => {
          console.log(response);
        })
```

And then parsing when you receive it to use as you intended:

```
var nav = JSON.parse(params.nav);
SheetName.getRange("F2").setValue(nav[0].style);
SheetName.getRange("G2").setValue(nav[1].style);
SheetName.getRange("H2").setValue(nav[2].style);
```